# Query from array passed in to Cosmos DB query?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

If I want all item ids that are not in a static list of ids, the SQL is straightforward:

```
SELECT VALUE i.id FROM i where i.id NOT IN ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

What if I want the opposite of that? Is it possible to return the values in the passed array that do not have corresponding item ids? I've tried a few options with `JOIN` without success.

The use case for this is for filtering in batches. Given an array of ids, I don't want to have to check if each individual id has a corresponding item in the database with a separate API call.

---

Based on feedback, here's a more detailed description:

I want to pass in a parameter that is an array of document ids. Something like `@TestIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']`

I want to find out which of those ids in `@TestIds` does not have a corresponding document. So, if there exists a document with an id of 'id2', I would expect the output of my query to be an array containing 'id1' and 'id3'.

The following does not work, but is roughly what I was trying to achieve:

```
SELECT VALUE t from @TestIds WHERE t NOT IN (SELECT c.id FROM c)
```

Comment: Can you please edit to show some sample input data and expected output? It's not clear what, exactly, you're asking for. Also, it would help if you showed what you tried, to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've added more to the explanation that I hope makes this clear.

Comment: Have you considered using `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`? Seems like that would be a better approach, to compare each found `id` against an actual array of `id`.

Comment: No, because that would only give me the document ids that match the array ids. I want the array ids that don't match a document id. Something like this might work, but doesn't: `SELECT VALUE x from ['suppressedaddress-1', 'suppressedaddress-2', 'suppressedaddress-3']
WHERE NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS ((SELECT t.id FROM t), x)`

Comment: I tried with query and also using udf. In both cases data is retrieving from the db but not from static list. Id's which are not present in the db, shows as NULL. By observing this i hope we cannot print the values which are not present in the db. Static list is used only to compare the id's in db.